# How to Calculate Azimuth in Python

Tags: python, gis, points, azimuth

I have two points in 3d demension (x,y,z) and I want to calculate the **Azimuth** between then using Python3. Thanks ahead.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not used to do you're work but ask question related to a problem. So, please try something and ask some help if you're stuck on a blocking problem.

Comment: Search the definition of azimuth and how to compute it from 1 point to another or for 1 vectors and then you can try to code the formula you find in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this,

In analytic geometry,

The distance  = SQRT((x2 –x1)2+(y2 –y1)2+(z2 –z1)2)

The plunge    = arcsin ((z2 – z1) / distance)

The azimuth   = arctan((x2 –x1)/(y2 –y1)) (always in two dimensions)

The value θ returned will be in the range of ±90° and must be corrected to give the true azimuth over the range of 0 to 360°

```
import math
x1,y1,z1 = 5.0,6.7,1.5
x2,y2,z2 = 4.0,1.2,1.6
distance = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2+(z2 -z1)**2)
print(distance)
# 5.5910642993977451
plunge = math.degrees(math.asin((z2-z1)/distance))
print(plunge)
# 1.0248287567800018 # the resulting dip_plunge is positive downward if z2 > z1
azimuth = math.degrees(math.atan2((x2-x1),(y2-y1)))
print(azimuth)
# -169.69515353123398 # = 360 + azimuth = 190.30484646876602 or  180+ azimuth = 10.304846468766016 over the range of 0 to 360°
```