# Function to calculate Azimuth

Tags: python, coordinates, gis, points, azimuth

I have two coordinates in the world and I need to calculate the **Azimuth** between them, Is there some function in Python3 to calculate it for me just by entering the two coordinates?

The coordinates are  X,Y,Z in Meters and in "**UTM WGS84**" Coordinate System.
I know there is some long way to do it I just dont know how and I prefer a short way to do it. Thanks.

Example of two Coordinates(In Meters):

**X1=10.3, Y1=20.4, Z1=4.8**

**X2=14.2, Y2=35.1, Z2=5.0**

If there is some more information I need to add plz tell me and I will add it.

Comment: you just asked this very question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506057/how-to-calculate-azimuth-in-python)

Comment: I'm sorry the first time I asked it I was in a hurrt and I realized I didnt asked it well so I got an answer thats wasn't good for me but good for my question so I asked it again to get the right answer for me..

Comment: pleas provide a [mre]

Comment: I'm sorry I dont have any code to give because It's a small problem from a big code and I don't know how to start coding this problem.

Comment: you have to show your efforts before anyone can help

Answer (score 0):

You can use geographiclib https://pypi.org/project/geographiclib/ which implements Karney's azimuth calculation.